# Booting with USB modem without Internet

Tags: 12.04, boot, networking, reboot, ubuntu-minimal

I have ubuntu 12.04 mini without desktop. This is ATM machine.

I have USB modem, that start with system. This modem don't have connection to Internet( but modem get IP, I use it to connect ot server). 
So when I'm trying to reboot I get message "Booting system without full network configuration without internet" and then I must press "Enter".

This PC will stay far away, so I can't press "Enter" after reboot. So are there any way to solve it? Maybe disable connection test or smth else?